# How can I backup an Azure RemoteApp VM?

Tags: azure, cloud, remoteapp

I want to be able to create a "disk image" of a RemoteApp VM so I can return it later to a certain state.

I've searched but not found any way to do this. *Is* there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ispiro

You can use Capture Image  and create a windows virtual machine so you can use it as template to create other virtual machines.

This virtual machine template includes the OS disk and any data disks attached the virtual machine except networking configuration.[image]

Comment: And how do I get that 'capture' button? I can't find it anywhere in the regular management, nor in the new portal. Remember I'm referring to RemoteApp, not to a regular VM.

Answer (score 0):

RemoteApp does currently NOT support capturing a VHD.
It is quite new on Azure, and does not have a lot of functionality as of yet.

Next time, I would suggest building your VM in Azure. Please refer to the following link for detailed instructions:
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/remoteapp-create-custom-image/

Then, from the moment you Sysprep, you will always have a VHD copy on Azure blob storage. :)
I hope this helps you out in the future.